# Find specific link w/ beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Hi I cannot figure out how to find links which begin with certain text for the life of me.
findall('a') works fine, but it's way too much. I just want to make a list of all links that begin with 
http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First set up a test document and open up the parser with BeautifulSoup:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> doc = '<html><body><div><a href="something">yep</a></div><div><a href="http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=3">somelink</a></div><a href="http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=7">another</a></body></html>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <a href="something">
    yep
   </a>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a href="http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=3">
    somelink
   </a>
  </div>
  <a href="http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=7">
   another
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Next, we can search for all `<a>` tags with an `href` attribute starting with `http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=`. You can use a regular expression for it:

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('^http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm\?id='))
[<a href="http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=3">somelink</a>, <a href="http://www.nhl.com/ice/boxscore.htm?id=7">another</a>]
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I guess the beautifulsoup documentation presupposes fluency in regex. Thank you for showing me that

Comment: Good but what if your attribute name is called "class" ?

Comment: Just use: ``kwargs={'class':foo}`` then ``soup.findAll('a', **kwargs)``

Comment: just found that we can use class_ to refer to class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794532/python-regular-expression-for-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 2):

You might not need BeautifulSoup since your search is specific

```
>>> import re
>>> links = re.findall("http:\/\/www\.nhl\.com\/ice\/boxscore\.htm\?id=.+", str(doc))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all links and than filter that list to get only links that you need. This will be very fast solution regardless the fact that you filter it afterwards.

```
listOfAllLinks = soup.findAll('a')
listOfLinksINeed = []

for link in listOfAllLinks:
    if "www.nhl.com" in link:
        listOfLinksINeed.append(link['href'])
```