# Python regular expression for Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to pull out specific div tags, and it seems I can't use
simple string matching.

The page has some tags in the form of

```
<div class="comment form new"...>
```

which I want to ignore, and also some tags in the form of

```
<div class="comment comment-xxxx...">
```

where the x's represent an integer of arbitrary length, and the ellipses represents an arbitrary number of other values separated by white spaces (that I'm not concerned about). I can't figure out the 
correct regex expression, especially since I've never used python's re class.

Using

```
soup.find_all(class_="comment")
```

finds all tags starting with the word comment. I have tried using

```
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile(r'(comment)( )(comment)'))
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile(r'comment comment.*'))
```

and lots of other variations, but I think I'm missing something obvious here about how regex expressions or match() work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: First, are you using BS3, or BS4? One has `findAll`, one has `find_all`, neither has `findall`…

Comment: Sorry, BS4 - I did not paste directly from my code, will edit.

Comment: Damn, because I had an answer for BS3… but for BS4, it looks like it doesn't like spaces in classes maybe? Or maybe I just don't know BS4 well enough. I can match `'comment'`, but not `'comment comment'`. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
>>> [div['class'] for div in soup.find_all('div')]
[['comment', 'form', 'new'], ['comment', 'comment-xxxx...']]
```

Notice that, unlike the equivalent in BS3, it's not this:

```
['comment form new', 'comment comment-xxxx...']
```

And that's why your regexps won't match.

But you can match, e.g., this:

```
>>> soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('comment-'))
[<div class="comment comment-xxxx..."></div>]
```

Note that BS does the equivalent of `re.search`, not `re.match`, so you don't need `'comment-.*'`. Of course if you want to match `'comment-12345'` but not `'comment-of-another-kind` you'd want, e.g., `'comment-\d+'`.

Comment: I remember reading something about this in the BS4 documentation, but it's still counterintuitive. Thanks very much! I beat my head against this for an hour+.

Comment: @user1890572: I'm not sure why, but I still haven't read through the BS4 docs beyond a quick third-party "migrating from BS3" guide, so I've gotten used to muddling through problems like this in my own code. Just think, if I were smarter, I wouldn't have been able to answer. :)