# BeautifulSoup findall using regex to find class A OR class B

Tags: regex, python-3.x, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to find, in order, class="A" and class="B". In other words, I want to use an OR operator so it prints out the results in proper order. Here are my attempts and results:

```
#Attempt #1
print(soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class": re.compile(r"Some Text A|Some Text B" )}))

#Attempt #2
soup.findAll("li", {'class':['Some Text A', 'Some Text B']})

#Attempt #3
print(soup.find_all("li", class_= re.compile(r"Some Text A|Some Text B" )))
```

All attempts have given me an empty list as results, yet there should be 46 results. I can do both classes individually, but I can't figure out how to do them simultaneously. It's important to note that these are two classes that aren't attributed to the same `li` at the same time, but two different classes that output different results.

No stackoverflow answers have worked so far. I am working with python 3.4 and Beautifulsoup 4

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial solution. For some reason, regex wouldn't work properly when the string "A" or/and the string "B" would contain spaces. For example :

This doesn't work:

```
print(soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class": re.compile(r"Some Text A|Some Text B" )}))
```

however this works:

```
print(soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class": re.compile(r"A|B" )}))
```

Thankfully my string was still precise enough while excluding the text after the space. I would appreciate an explanation or workaround for searches involving strings that contain spaces when using regex.

Comment: That's because `Some Text A` represented as three separate CSS classes : `Some`, `Text`, and `A`. Former discussion regarding the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13794740/2998271