# BeautifulSoup returns empty list when searching by compound class names

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

BeautifulSoup returns empty list when searching by compound class names using regex.

Example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bs = 
    """
    <a class="name-single name692" href="www.example.com"">Example Text</a>
    """

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(bs)

# this returns the class
found_elements = bsObj.find_all("a", class_= re.compile("^(name-single.*)$"))

# this returns an empty list
found_elements = bsObj.find_all("a", class_= re.compile("^(name-single name\d*)$"))
```

I need the class selection to be very precise. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, because class attribute values are treated as lists/arrays of values separated with space.

Comment: Well, I have been searching for a solution once, but I could not. I just suggest to do it in 2 steps: 1) get all anchors with "name-single" class and 2) get those that also match the `^name\d*$` regex.

Comment: FYI, created a follow-up and a more generic question about handling the `class` attribute: [Disable special “class” attribute handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295928/disable-special-class-attribute-handling).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you try to make a regular expression match on a class attribute value that contains multiple classes, `BeautifulSoup` would apply the regular expression to every single class separately. Here are the relevant topics about the problem:

- [Python regular expression for Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794532/python-regular-expression-for-beautiful-soup)
- [Multiple CSS class search is unhandy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1157869)

This is all because [`class` is a very special multi-valued attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) and every time you parse HTML, one of the `BeautifulSoup`'s tree builders (depending on the parser choice) internally splits a class string value into a list of classes (quote from the `HTMLTreeBuilder`'s docstring):

```
# The HTML standard defines these attributes as containing a
# space-separated list of values, not a single value. That is,
# class="foo bar" means that the 'class' attribute has two values,
# 'foo' and 'bar', not the single value 'foo bar'.  When we
# encounter one of these attributes, we will parse its value into
# a list of values if possible. Upon output, the list will be
# converted back into a string.
```

---

There are multiple workarounds, but here is a hack-ish one - we are going to ask `BeautifulSoup` not to handle `class` as a multi-valued attribute by making our simple custom tree builder:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.builder._htmlparser import HTMLParserTreeBuilder


class MyBuilder(HTMLParserTreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBuilder, self).__init__()

        # BeautifulSoup, please don't treat "class" specially
        self.cdata_list_attributes["*"].remove("class")


bs = """<a class="name-single name692" href="www.example.com"">Example Text</a>"""
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(bs, "html.parser", builder=MyBuilder())
found_elements = bsObj.find_all("a", class_=re.compile(r"^name\-single name\d+$"))

print(found_elements)
```

In this case the regular expression would be applied to a `class` attribute value as a whole.

---

Alternatively, you can just parse the HTML with `xml` features enabled (if this is applicable):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
```

---

You can also use [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and match all elements with `name-single` class and a class staring with "name":

```
soup.select("a.name-single,a[class^=name]")
```

You can then apply the regular expression manually if needed:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"^name-single name\d+$")
for elm in bsObj.select("a.name-single,a[class^=name]"):
    match = pattern.match(" ".join(elm["class"]))
    if match:
        print(elm)
```

Comment: Great answer. Does the MyBuilder option have any side effects, something not working/working differently after this hack?

Answer (score 1):

For this use case I would simply use a [custom filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function), like so:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.builder._htmlparser import HTMLParserTreeBuilder

def myclassfilter(tag):
    return re.compile(r"^name\-single name\d+$").search(' '.join(tag['class']))

bs = """<a class="name-single name692" href="www.example.com"">Example Text</a>"""
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(bs, "html.parser")
found_elements = bsObj.find_all(myclassfilter)

print(found_elements)
```