# Disable special "class" attribute handling

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

**The Story:**

When you parse HTML with `BeautifulSoup`, `class` attribute is considered a [multi-valued attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) and is handled in a special manner:

> Remember that a single tag can have multiple values for its “class” attribute. When you search for a tag that matches a certain CSS class, you’re matching against any of its CSS classes.

Also, a quote from a built-in `HTMLTreeBuilder` used by `BeautifulSoup` as a base for other tree builder classes, like, for instance, `HTMLParserTreeBuilder`:

```
# The HTML standard defines these attributes as containing a
# space-separated list of values, not a single value. That is,
# class="foo bar" means that the 'class' attribute has two values,
# 'foo' and 'bar', not the single value 'foo bar'.  When we
# encounter one of these attributes, we will parse its value into
# a list of values if possible. Upon output, the list will be
# converted back into a string.
```

**The Question:**

How can I configure `BeautifulSoup` to handle `class` as a usual single-valued attribute? In other words, I don't want it to handle `class` specially and consider it a regular attribute.

FYI, here is one of the use-cases when it can be helpful:

- [BeautifulSoup returns empty list when searching by compound class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288969/beautifulsoup-returns-empty-list-when-searching-by-compound-class-names/34294195#34294195)

**What I've tried:**

I've actually made it work by making a *custom tree builder class* and removing `class` from the list of specially-handled attributes:

```
from bs4.builder._htmlparser import HTMLParserTreeBuilder

class MyBuilder(HTMLParserTreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBuilder, self).__init__()

        # BeautifulSoup, please don't treat "class" specially
        self.cdata_list_attributes["*"].remove("class")


soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser", builder=MyBuilder())
```

What I don't like in this approach is that it is quite "unnatural" and "magical" involving importing "private" internal `_htmlparser`. I hope there is a simpler way.

<sup>NOTE: I want to save all other HTML parsing related features, meaning I don't want to parse `HTML` with "xml"-only features (which could've been another workaround).</sup>

Comment: I thought it was a bug when I saw your avatar under a beautifulsoup question with no answer and then I realized you *asked* the question!  I can't help you everything I tried didn't work or involved two iterations.

Comment: I do not know how to do this, but for the specific use case provided as example I provided a different answer (so I posted it there). It is simpler in my opinion but may not be sufficient for other use cases

Comment: Using it as a css selector?. Maybe in that case the simplest option could be not to use a common class selector, but an attribute selector. Selector '.myclass' is just the same that '[class=~"myclass"]', but selector '[class="class"]' is an element whose "class" attribute value is exactly equal to "myclass" (not myclass in a space sepated list).

Comment: @miguel-svq good point, CSS selectors might help here depending on the use case. If we take that use case from a linked question, there is a regular expression pattern applied to a class attribute - this is something we cannot really achieve with CSS selectors, but, we can use them to narrow down the search and then do some manual checks. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I don't like in this approach is that it is quite "unnatural" and "magical" involving importing "private" internal `_htmlparser`. I hope there is a simpler way.

Yes, you can import it from `bs4.builder` instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.builder import HTMLParserTreeBuilder

class MyBuilder(HTMLParserTreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyBuilder, self).__init__()
        # BeautifulSoup, please don't treat "class" as a list
        self.cdata_list_attributes["*"].remove("class")


soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser", builder=MyBuilder())
```

And if it's important enough that you don't want to repeat yourself, put the builder in its own module, and register it with `register_treebuilders_from()` so that it takes precedence.

Comment: While this works, I hate that my IDEs (PyCharm and IntelliJ IDEA with Python plugin) complain about the `bs4.builder` import.  They say "Unresolved reference 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder'" and it can't jump to the declaration for it when I ask for it.  Are other IDEs any better about this?

Answer (score 2):

The class `HTMLParserTreeBuilder` is actually declared on the [upper module](https://git.kaarsemaker.net/beautifulsoup/blob/451028fc0b80316c8897bbfaf71fe9b109a1ff97/bs4/builder/__init__.py) `_init__.py`, so there is no need to import directly from the private submodule. That said I would do it the following way:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.builder import HTMLParserTreeBuilder

bb = HTMLParserTreeBuilder()
bb.cdata_list_attributes["*"].remove("class")

soup = BeautifulSoup(bs, "html.parser", builder=bb)
found_elements = soup.find_all(class_=re.compile(r"^name\-single name\d+$"))
print found_elements
```

It is basically the same as defining the class as in the OP (maybe a bit more explicit), but I don't think there is a better way to do it.