# BeautifulSoup4 class with whitespaces not treated as single string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="class1 class2 class3">...</div>','lxml')
>>> soup.find('div')['class']
['class1', 'class2', 'class3']
```

How can i force BS4 to treat class name as a single string?

Comment: Related (or may be a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295928/disable-special-class-attribute-handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xml` as the parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="class1 class2 class3">...</div>',"xml")
print(soup.find('div')['class'])
class1 class2 class3
```

Or you could remove  `'class'` from  `builder.cdata_list_attributes['*']`:

```
del BeautifulSoup().builder.cdata_list_attributes["*"][0]

soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="class1 class2 class3">...</div>')
print(soup.find('div')['class'])
class1 class2 class3
```