# Extracting tags with multivalued attributes

Tags: regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

i'm experimenting with the following code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
htmlsource1 = """<div class="small-12 columns ">
                    <h5 class="clsname1 large-text seq2">text1</h5>
                    <h5 class="clsname1 small-text seq1">text2</h5>
                    <h5 class="clsname1 seq1 small-text clsname2">text3</h5>
                 </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource1, "html.parser")
interesting_h5s = soup.find_all('h5', class_=re.compile('^(?=.*\bsmall-text\b)(?=.*\bseq1\b).*$'))
for h5 in interesting_h5s:
    print h5
```

My purpose is to extract the h5 tags that contain both "small-text' and 'seq1' classes (in any order) but for some reason it's not functioning in spite of the regex being tested positively in http://pythex.org.

For the regex I adapted the answer provided in  [Regex to match string containing two names in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order)

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup returns empty list when searching by compound class names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288969/beautifulsoup-returns-empty-list-when-searching-by-compound-class-names)

Answer (score 0):

## Foreward

You should really use an html parsing tool, but it seems that you have creative control over you HTML so the possible edge cases will be limited.

## Description

`<h5(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\sclass=['"](?=[^"]*\bsmall-text\b)(?=[^"]*\bseq1\b)([^"]*)['"]?)(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?\/?>(.*?)</h5>`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- extract the h5 tags that contain both "small-text' and 'seq1' classes (in any order)
- avoid some difficult edge cases

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/fR0mT7/2

**Sample text**

Note the difficult edge cases in the last two `h5` tags

```
<div class="small-12 columns ">
   <h5 class="clsname1 large-text seq2">text1</h5>
   <h5 class="clsname1 small-text seq1">text2</h5>
   <h5 class="clsname1 seq1 small-text clsname2">text3</h5>
   <h5 onmouseover=' class="small-text seq1" ; ' class="clsname1 large-text seq2">text4</h5>
   <h5 onmouseover=' class="small-text seq1" ; ' class="clsname1 small-text seq1">text5</h5>
   </div>
```

**Sample Matches**

- Capture Group 0 gets the entire `h5` tag
- Capture Group 1 gets the entire value from the class attribute
- Capture Group 2 gets the inner text from the `h5` tag

```
[0][0] = <h5 class="clsname1 small-text seq1">text2</h5>
[0][1] = clsname1 small-text seq1
[0][2] = text2

[1][0] = <h5 class="clsname1 seq1 small-text clsname2">text3</h5>
[1][1] = clsname1 seq1 small-text clsname2
[1][2] = text3

[2][0] = <h5 onmouseover=' class="small-text seq1" ; ' class="clsname1 small-text seq1">text5</h5>
[2][1] = clsname1 small-text seq1
[2][2] = text5
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <h5                      '<h5'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^'"]                    any character except: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^\s>]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    class=                   'class='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]                     any character of: ''', '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      small-text               'small-text'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      seq1                     'seq1'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ['"]?                    any character of: ''', '"' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ='                       '=\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ="                       '="'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^'"\s]*                 any character except: ''', '"',
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  </h5>                    '</h5>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Disable special "class" attribute handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295928/disable-special-class-attribute-handling) article, the issue was solved by adding the following lines of code:

```
from bs4.builder import HTMLParserTreeBuilder

bb = HTMLParserTreeBuilder()
bb.cdata_list_attributes["*"].remove("class")

soup = BeautifulSoup(bs, "html.parser", builder=bb)
```