# Selecting Tags With Multiple Part Class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data off a webpage, that has `div` tags that have multiple part tags. E.g. `<div class="A">`, `<div class="A B">` and `<div class="A X Y">`. I want to collect the tags of the first two types, but not the last.

I thought that this would be simple enough using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib import request

url_request = request.Request(url)
html = request.urlopen(url_request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": re.compile("A( B)?$")})
```

When I look at `divs` though, I see that all the `<div class="A X Y">` tags are there too.

The problem appears to be that BeautifulSoup considers the class to be a list, rather than a string:

```
>> div['class']
>> ['A', 'X', 'Y']
```

Can I use regular expressions (or anything else) to remove the unwanted tags? I'd prefer to ignore them, rather than post-select the tags I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `class` is a *multi-valued attribute*. Here is a quite detailed story in a context of a similar problem: [BeautifulSoup returns empty list when searching by compound class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288969/beautifulsoup-returns-empty-list-when-searching-by-compound-class-names).

---

As a workaround, you can make a *filtering function*:

```
def filter_function(elm):
    return elm and "class" in elm.attrs and "A" in elm["class"] and "Y" not in elm["class"]
```

Complete example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
     <div class="A">test1</div>
     <div class="A B">test2</div>
     <div class="A X Y">test3</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

def filter_function(elm):
    return elm and "class" in elm.attrs and "A" in elm["class"] and "Y" not in elm["class"]

for div in soup.find_all(filter_function):
    print(div.text)
```

Prints:

```
test1
test2
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can request BeautifulSoup select tags using a filter function.

```
html = '<html><body><div class="A"/><div class="A B"/><div class="A X Y"/></body></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
soup.find_all('div', {'class':'A'})
[<div class="A"></div>, <div class="A B"></div>, <div class="A X Y"></div>]

def f(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('class') and 'X' not in tag['class']

soup.find_all(f)
[<div class="A"></div>, <div class="A B"></div>]
```

You can write arbitrarily complex rules in that filter function to get whatever result you want.