# Using BeautifulSoup to find all tags containing a AND NOT containing b

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 to pull out li tags with class of js-stream-item but not containing scroll-bump-user-card from the following. (which is getting a, b only)

```
<li class="js-stream-item stream-item ">a<li>
<li class="js-stream-item stream-item stream-item ">b<li>
<li class="js-stream-item stream-item scroll-bump-user-card ">c<li>
```

There are two ways I am thinking of.

1. Using `soup.find_all('li', class_=re.compile('js-stream-item'))` to get all tags and removed the tag with scroll-bump-user-card then.
2. Using `[tag.extract() for tag in soup.find_all('li', class_=re.compile('scroll-bump-user-card'))]` to delete first, then find all after.

**The question is** if there's a decent way to get a, b by editing the regex with AND NOT syntax in `re.compile()`.

**Update** I re-wrote first option of alecxe's answer into one single long line as following:

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: re.compile('js-stream-item').search(str(tag))
                      and not re.compile('scroll-bump-user-card').search(str(tag))
                      and tag.name == 'li')
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `class` is a special [multi-valued attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) which requires [special handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294195/771848).

One option is to use a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and check the presence of `js-stream-item` class and absence of `scroll-bump-user-card` class:

```
def search_function(tag):
    if tag.name == "li":
        class_ = tag.get("class", [])
        return "js-stream-item" in class_ and "scroll-bump-user-card" not in class_

for li in soup.find_all(search_function):
    print(li.get_text(strip=True))
```

---

Another option would be to find all `li` with `js-stream-item` class and just skip `li` elements having `scroll-bump-user-card` class:

```
for li in soup.select("li.js-stream-item"):
    if "scroll-bump-user-card" in li["class"]:
        continue
    print(li.get_text(strip=True))
```

---

Another, to check that `class` ends with `stream-item` with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) (don't use this):

```
for li in soup.select("li[class$=' stream-item ']"):
    print(li.get_text(strip=True))
```

---

Note that a better CSS selector for this use case would be:

```
li.js-stream-item:not(.scroll-bump-user-card)
```

but it is not going to work because of the limited CSS selector support in `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Thanks! I rewrote your first option into one line updated in my post. Any suggestion on it? I also researched some regex, trying something like ^(?!.*scroll-bump).*js-stream-item, but no luck. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @PhantomKidding well, I am not sure why are you trying to do the first option in one line and modify it to do a regular expression search. Plus, have you looked through what a multi-valued attribute means in the linked answer? You don't get class as a single string - it is a list of strings - each for every class. Thanks.