# Beautifulsoup return list for attribute "class" while value for other attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

[Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is handy for html parsing in python, and below code result cofuse me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tr ="""
<table>
    <tr class="passed" id="row1"><td>t1</td></tr>
    <tr class="failed" id="row2"><td>t2</td></tr>
</table>
"""
table = BeautifulSoup(tr,"html.parser")
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    print row["class"]
    print row["id"]
```

result:

```
[u'passed']
row1
[u'failed']
row2
```

Why the attribute `class` returns as array ? while `id` is normal value ?

`beautifulsoup4-4.5.0` is used with `python 2.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`class`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) is a special [multi-valued attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) in `BeautifulSoup`:

> HTML 4 defines a few attributes that can have multiple values. HTML 5
>   removes a couple of them, but defines a few more. The most common
>   multi-valued attribute is `class` (that is, a tag can have more than one
>   CSS class)

Sometimes, this is problematic to deal with - for instance, when you want to apply a regular expression to `class` attribute value as a whole:

- [BeautifulSoup returns empty list when searching by compound class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288969/beautifulsoup-returns-empty-list-when-searching-by-compound-class-names)

You can [turn this behavior off by tweaking the tree builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294195/771848), but I would not recommend doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Because elements may have multiple classes.

Consider this example:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
tr ="""
<table>
    <tr class="passed a b c" id="row1"><td>t1</td></tr>
    <tr class="failed" id="row2"><td>t2</td></tr>
</table>
"""
table = BeautifulSoup(tr,"html.parser")
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    print row["class"]
    print row["id"]

['passed', 'a', 'b', 'c']
row1
['failed']
row2
```

Comment: thank for quick answer, with the accepted answer from @alecxe, i notice `class` is a special attribute in html and bs4